# The first iPad iPad one?

Tags: ipad

I have the first iPad ever made not the actual first iPad ever made but the first version and I can’t download apps because all the apps are out of its legal how do I get a older versions of the apps? Onto the iPad

Comment: Buy the app (Netflix say), on a newer device, and you may be able to download it (for SD content).

Comment: Not a duplicate, please read both questions again. Suggested duplicate is an OS restriction. This is an unclear question but seems related to the device support.

Answer (score 1):

You can't get those apps to run. Just make sure that your iPad is as up to date as it can possibly get.

Many apps have updated to support the new hardware and software.

I recommend to try using a browser for things like social networks and etc.